# How to using powershell, download and save the recieved user photo from microsoft Graph API

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

```
$apiUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value"
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($Tokenresponse.access_token)"} -Uri $apiUrl -Method Get
```

This gets me a response like below:

```
@odata.context          : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('48db12f7-f809-4ff0-a55c-ab05e135c092')/photo/$entity
@odata.mediaContentType : image/jpeg
@odata.mediaEtag        : "D4976167"
id                      : 360X360
height                  : 360
width                   : 360
```

i am not getting a way on how to go for next step.
my objective is to:
1. Save the photo to a variable ( i believe as a byte array). or
2. Or get the photo directly downloaded to a .jpeg file.

Answer (score 0):

Finally from another question in here i could figure out the problem with my code.
[The solution was to escape the $value at the end of the url with `$value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51491295/image-url-of-a-signed-in-user-using-microsoft-graph?rq=1)